# jQuery scrollTop doesn't animate in FF or IE but working fine in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollto

Already tried with $(window) or $(document) they're not working either.

```
$('a[href^="#"').on('click', function () {
    var id = $(this).attr("href");
    var target = $(id).offset().top;

    //Animation
    $('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: target }, 500);
       return false;

});
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2eLjbfms/4/)

Comment: btw, you forgot to pass `event` into event callback.

Comment: Can you create a simple http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Here's the link to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2eLjbfms/1/ 
@Huangism

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2eLjbfms/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the closing `]` in your selector so it is throwing an error and not hooking up the click handler.

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (event) {
```

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2eLjbfms/6/)